# Does centripetal force exists with centrifugal force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, centripetal-force, centrifugal-force

Is it true that where centrifugal force is in action, centripetal force is also existing. Can someone explain this through examples such as a centrifuge or centrifugal pump?

Comment: It is just a standard misconception that you can find anywhere. There are many duplicates, here is one: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/86345/

Comment: I deleted some comments that were either inappropriate or unnecessary.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8891/2451 and links therein.

Comment: ObXKCD: https://xkcd.com/123/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **centripetal** force is a **real** force that changes the direction of an object's motion (e.g. to make it perform circular orbits). An example of a centripetal force is the force of gravity between the Sun and the planets that make the planets orbit the Sun.

The **centrifugal** force is a **virtual** force that appears if one makes a coordinate transformation from an inertial reference frame to a rotating reference frame. It is simply a manifestation of inertia in a non-inertial reference frame (e.g. the "feeling" of being "pushed out" when you make a turn in your car).

Whether you are dealing with centripetal force or centrifugal force depends on your **reference frame**. If you are working in an inertial reference frame, then you are dealing with a centripetal force that changes the direction of motion of the object you are examining. If you are in the rotating frame of the object, then you are dealing with a centrifugal force as a manifestation of inertia in a reference frame which is not inertial.